# Correct method of implementing a recursive function in C?

Tags: recursion

I am trying to implement a recursive function into a piece of code. I have tried multiple methods but I can't quite get it right. I was wondering if there was anything I might have overlooked or if I didn't do it correctly at all.

For reference, the question I am trying to answer is the Waterloo CCC 2013 J3

```
#include <stdio.h>
int year, counter = 0, tempNum;

int isDistinct (int num) {
  tempNum = num;
  int number[10] = { 0 };
  while (tempNum > 0) {
    if (number[tempNum % 10] == 1) {num++; isDistinct(num);}
    else { number[tempNum % 10] = 1; tempNum /= 10; } 
  } 
  return num;
}

int main() {
  scanf("%d", &year);
  printf("%d", isDistinct(year+1));
}
```

Comment: `but I can't quite get it right` ... what is not right about this code?  Have you tried stepping through it on sample data using a debugger?

Comment: I just did what you said, my code counts up to the correct answer, but then goes down back to the original figure, do you know what may cause that.

Comment: Yes, this is what the modulus (remainder) function does.

Comment: I edited my code, but what happens when I add diagnostic printf statements is that I find I approach the correct number, but then it counts back down. My code has nothing that would decrease the num integer so I am very confused